Is there any test I can apply to the data to tell whether the adaptive LASSO or the LASSO is likely to perform better in prediction?
Is there a. test I can perform on a sample that will tell me if coefficients estimated using the LASSO, the adaptive LASSO, or the relaxed adaptive LASSO are likely to give better (in the mean squared error sense) predictions when applied to out-of-sample data?
I am under the impression, based on reading some papers I did not fully understand, that the adaptive lasso is almost always better (has the oracle property) at the cost of sometimes failing disastrously in a few special circumstances (as with the Hodge and James-Stein estimators when the true mean is exactly zero).

the failure mode you are mentioning has to do with what the true value of the coefficients are, not directly with what the data look like. Hence, I have to admit that I doubt that a procedure which does not involve estimating those coefficients somehow exists.

In the same way as you decide the regularisation parameter you can decide the type of regularisation.
